# Swift - Creating a means to return UIViewControllers which conform to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm trying to write code which returns a viewController, which conforms to a protocol, as determined by the key passed in to the subscript -

```
struct ViewControllerName {

    // keys -

    static var pushNotification: Identifier<PushNotificationPresenting> { .init(name: "PushNotificationViewController") }
    static var termsAndConditions: Identifier<TermsPresenting> { .init(name: "TermsAndConditionsViewController") }

    // give me the viewController

    static subscript<T>(identifier: Identifier<T>) -> T? {
        get {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: identifier.name, bundle: nil)
            return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier.name) as? T
        }
    }

    struct Identifier<T> {
        let name: String
    }
}
```

So this code works, in that it returns an object which conforms to the protocol, but I'd like it to return a UIViewController which conforms, eg -

```
static subscript<T>(identifier: Identifier<T>) -> (UIViewController & T)? {
    get {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: identifier.name, bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier.name) as? (UIViewController & T)
    }
}
```

However, that doesn't compile. Is it even possible? It would be nice to not have to do the 'as? UIViewController' dance in my consuming code. Any thoughts welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a type `UIViewController & T`, then you should create a new type that subclasses UIViewController and implements T, and just provide that as the generic parameter of your method.

If you don't want to create a new type, then you should extend the `UIViewController` class so that it conforms to T, and then just provide UIViewController as the generic parameter of your method.

Now, you might be wanting to create a new type somehow 'on the fly', but I think that you cannot do that. You have to explicitly declare it. Therefore I think the first solution I provided is the one you might be looking for.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing this myself anyway (ie, UIViewController which implements T), but yours is the correct answer! I would have liked to have been able to constrain the ViewControllerName struct somehow so that T had to be a UIViewController, then use that plus the protocol T of the subscript, to return UIViewController & T, but I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

you want to get type `UIViewController`, this method return `UIViewController`

```
static subscript<T>(identifier: Identifier<T>) -> UIViewController? {
    get {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: identifier.name, bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address the requirement that the returned value also conform to a protocol